# Access anonymous array using NgRepeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a multi-level array containing some objects at its deepest level.

```
[  
   [  
      [  
         "FUND",
         {  
            "totassets":10.9,
            "totdate":"2015-03-23",
            "expratiogross":1.35,
            "exprationet":1.08
         }
      ],
      [  
         "DAILY",
         {  
            "navdate":"2015-03-23",
            "nav":10.05,
            "chgamt":0,
            "chgpct":0,
            "pop":10.05,
            "ytdreturn":2.03,
            "curr7dayyield":0,
            "eff7dayyield":0,
            "unsub7dayyield":0,
            "30dayyield":0,
            "30dayloadyield":0
         }
      ]
   ]
]
```

I would like to use ngRepeat to display all the items in "FUND" or "DAILY" but I'm unsure how to access objects this deep without names for each of the arrays above.

Sorry if this is a basic question but I wasn't able to find an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to get the first element of your two outer arrays.

```
$scope.obj = [  
   [  
      [  
         "FUND",
         {  
            "totassets":10.9,
            "totdate":"2015-03-23",
            "expratiogross":1.35,
            "exprationet":1.08
         }
      ],
      [  
         "DAILY",
         {  
            "navdate":"2015-03-23",
            "nav":10.05,
            "chgamt":0,
            "chgpct":0,
            "pop":10.05,
            "ytdreturn":2.03,
            "curr7dayyield":0,
            "eff7dayyield":0,
            "unsub7dayyield":0,
            "30dayyield":0,
            "30dayloadyield":0
         }
      ]
   ]
]

<ng-repeat el in obj[0][0]>
  <span>totassets: {{el[0].FUND.totalAssets}}</span>
  <span>navdate: {{el[0].DAILY.navdate}}</span>
</ng-repeat>
```

Comment: Given how quickly you answered that, I'd say my question was really easy. Thanks much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

An issue you have with the array is that even when you ignore the outer arrays, you're still left with two individual arrays a la:

```
  [  
     "FUND",
     {  
        "totassets":10.9,
        "totdate":"2015-03-23",
        "expratiogross":1.35,
        "exprationet":1.08
     }
  ],
```

And:

```
  [  
     "DAILY",
     {  
        "navdate":"2015-03-23",
        "nav":10.05,
        "chgamt":0,
        "chgpct":0,
        "pop":10.05,
        "ytdreturn":2.03,
        "curr7dayyield":0,
        "eff7dayyield":0,
        "unsub7dayyield":0,
        "30dayyield":0,
        "30dayloadyield":0
     }
  ]
```

So you will need two `ngRepeat` blocks to achieve what I assume you want to achieve as well as going *one level deeper* to actually access the values you want.

Here's a quick plnkr to demonstrate what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/ArCh8q8w2JoXsg107XwP?p=preview